# Nested Loop in Eloquent in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am having trouble with my code. I have two tables Stocks and StockLists however, I want to get all the related stock in the stocks list based on the stock code. But the result is repeated in each stocks....
Here is the link of the image https://www.screencast.com/t/rHdT2gigh

```
public function index()
{
    $stocks = Stock::all();
     foreach ($stocks as $stock) {
        $stockInfos = DB::table('stocksList')
        ->where('stockCode', $stock->stockCode)
        ->take(3)
        ->get();
     }
     return view('welcome', compact('stocks', 'stockInfos'));
}
```

Here is my blade.php

```
@forelse($stocks as $stock)
                    <tr align="left">
                        <th scope="row">{{ $stock->stockCode }}</th>
                        <td><strong>{{ $stock->stockName }}</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>
                            @forelse($stockInfos as $stockInfo)
                            {{ $stockInfo->stockDate }} : {{ $stockInfo->stockPrice }}
                            <br>
                            @empty
                            <em>No Data</em>
                            @endforelse                            
                        </strong></td>    
                    </tr>
                    @empty
                    @endforelse
```

Comment: `$stockInfos[] = DB::table('stocksList')...`

Comment: can you please give details of stock and stocklist table?

Comment: @Steve what will I do on my blade.php upon using this?

Comment: @Nikita
 stock table has only stock code, while the stocklist has the list of prices every day.. [link](http://example.com)

Answer (score 1):

You are overwritting the `$stockInfos` variable try with

```
public function index()
{
    $stocks = Stock::all();
    $stockInfos = [];
     foreach ($stocks as $stock) {
        array_push($stockInfos,DB::table('stocksList')
        ->where('stockCode', $stock->stockCode)
        ->take(3)
        ->get());
     }
     return view('welcome', compact('stocks'))->with('stockInfos',collect($stockInfos));
}
```

And in your view :

```
@forelse($stocks as $stock)
      <tr align="left">
          <th scope="row">{{ $stock->stockCode }}</th>
          <td><strong>{{ $stock->stockName }}</strong></td>
          <td><strong>
                            @forelse($stockInfos->where('stockCode',$stock->stockCode) as $stockInfo)
                            {{ $stockInfo->stockDate }} : {{ $stockInfo->stockPrice }}
                            <br>
                            @empty
                            <em>No Data</em>
                            @endforelse                            
                        </strong></td>    
                    </tr>
                    @empty
                    @endforelse
```

Comment: Thank you but I get an error "Call to a member function where() on array"

Comment: I tried your updated code it works but it shows no data :(

Comment: do `dd($stocks,$stockInfos` right before the return in your controller and look for the data there, maybe the problem is in the query

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$stockInfos = DB::table('Stock')
             ->join('stocksList','stocksList.stockCode','=','Stock.stockCode')
             ->get();
```